# Is it better to convert screenshot PNGs to BMPs before compressing them into an archive (e.g. 7z)?

Tags: compression

As the question suggests, I have a shitton of screenshots as PNGs, but the compression ratio of 7z when I put them all together in one archive is pretty suboptimal. Many screenshots feature identical parts as other screenshots and I think it should be able to find those redundancies. But then I thought maybe the problem was that I was compressing PNGs and not actual uncompressed RGB data (BMP), thus the PNG compression was hindering the 7z compression.

Is that a plausible string of thought? How much could I expect to gain in terms of compression ratio when I use BMP? In theory it should be a lot, if 7z can find and utilize the redundancies throughout all files (many flat areas with the same color - website backgrounds - which often repeats itself throughout many pictures).

If 7z can't do it (find redundancies across many many pictures), what software can? WinRK perhaps?

Comment: What stops you from making a test with ten or hundred similar screenshots?

Comment: Frankly, laziness. Also, I am interested in the theory a little, so I figured I could get a more complete picture from someone who has experience in the field of compression.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to questions about which compression is better, it is impossible to say.  The effectiveness of a compression algorithm lies solely with the contents of the data being compressed.  One compression algorithm might compress one set of files more than another, yet that same algorithm might compress less on a different set.

In my opinion, PNG is optimized for images and I doubt you would be much more compression out of 7-zip.

However, there is one way to know for sure:  Test it.

Comment: That makes sense, but for one PNG compression is a bit older and for two, PNG only compresses within a single image.

I will probably have to try it eventually, yeah. I'll wait a little if someone comes around who has already done this.